# confused about the type of the Instance of a binary tree data type of Int Nodes in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, binary-tree

I made a binary tree data type in Haskell, according to this code:

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree
            | Node a 
            (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show,Eq)
```

and I also created a function to insert elements in the tree:

```
treeinsert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeinsert x EmptyTree = leaf x

treeinsert x (Node a left right)
         | x == a = Node x left right
         | x < a  = Node a (treeinsert x left) right
         | x > a = Node a left (treeinsert x right)
```

Now, for testing I am using a list of Int elements, like this:

```
    ghci> let nums = [8,6,4,1,7,3,5]  
    ghci> let numsTree = foldr treeInsert EmptyTree nums  
    ghci> numsTree  
Node 5 (Node 3 (Node 1 EmptyTree EmptyTree) (Node 4 EmptyTree EmptyTree)) (Node 7 (Node 6 EmptyTree EmptyTree) (Node 8 EmptyTree EmptyTree))
```

My question is when I check the type of numsTree:

```
:type numsTree
numsTree :: Tree Integer
```

Why doesn't it just have the type of "Tree"?

I am a little confused.
(sorry for my language)

Comment: Think about lists.  You can have `[Int]`, or `[String]`, or `[Bool]`, anything in the pattern `[a]`, where `a` is a type.  You can even have `[[b]]`, which would be where `a ~ [b]` (`~` is equality for types).  What this really is though is `[] Int`, `[] String`, `[] Bool`, etc.  The compiler just lets you use the far more convenient syntax of `[a]`, since lists are so common.  A list is a _parameterized_ type, and so is `Tree a`.  Types like this are very useful, since they let you make generic containers (and more, but that's for another post).

Answer (score 4):

You defined the type `Tree` as a parametrised type.  The `a` after `Tree` in the data type's  definition is this parameter.  This means that there is not just one `Tree` type, but many different ones.  For example, you can have a type `Tree Integer` containing integers, a type `Tree Bool` containing booleans and a type `Tree (String -> String)` containing functions from string to string.

Note that it's a good thing that you can distinguish these different types.  It means that when you get a value out of such a tree, you know which type of value you're going to get.  If there was just one `Tree` type, then you wouldn't be able to find out.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't it just have the type of "Tree"?

Because you explicitly pass the list of numbers to it which restricts the type.

If you define `nTree = foldr treeInsert`(in ghci prepend a `let`) you get the expected more general type. By the way, you may want to add `Leaf a` as another data constructor.